# ambiguous error in mysql recordset in Dreamweaver

Tags: mysql, sql, dreamweaver, recordset, mysql-error-1052

The following recordset in Dreamweaver throws a 1052 ambiguous error every time I attempt to test it. I know it has something to do with the dateADDED, but don't know how to fix it.

```
    SELECT commentID, commentTitle, commentContent, topicTable.topicTitle,  DAYNAME(dateADDED) as day, MONTHNAME(dateADDED) as month, 
DAY(dateADDED) as date, YEAR(dateADDED) as year
FROM commentTable, topicTable
WHERE commentID = colname AND topicTable.topidID = commentTable.topicID
```

Here is the layout of the tables,

```
CREATE TABLE userTable
(
userID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
screenName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
userPasswd CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
dateJoined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
lastlogin DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(userID)
)
;

CREATE TABLE categoryTable                                          
(
categoryID MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,                       
categoryName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                                  
categoryDescription VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,                          
PRIMARY KEY (categoryID)
)
;

CREATE TABLE topicTable                                             
(
topicID MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,                          
topicTitle VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                                    
userID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,                                        
dateAdded TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,             
categoryID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,                                      
PRIMARY KEY (topicID)
)
;

CREATE TABLE commentTable                                           
(
commentID MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,                        
commentTitle VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                                  
commentContent TEXT NOT NULL,                                       
userID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,                                        
dateAdded TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,             
topicID INT NOT NULL,                                               
PRIMARY KEY (commentID)
)
;
```

Comment: Well, what are the table schemas?

Comment: I just uploaded the tables

Answer (score 0):

`dateADDED` is represented in both tables, so you should choose from which one you want it to be in the result set :

```
SELECT ct.commentID
     , ct.commentTitle
     , ct.commentContent
     , tt.topicTitle
     , DAYNAME(ct.dateADDED) as `day`
     , MONTHNAME(ct.dateADDED) as `month`
     , DAY(ct.dateADDED) as `date`
     , YEAR(ct.dateADDED) as `year`
FROM commentTable ct
JOIN topicTable tt ON ct.commentID = tt.colname  AND tt.topidID = ct.topicID
```

By the way, still wonder, what `colname` stands for, maybe it should be `ct.userID = tt.userID` instead?

Comment: it doesn't really matter from which table, right? This is a web page to allow to edit a previous comment, so I assume from the comment table would be the best choice.

Comment: @Mike : If it is for comment, then take it from `commentTable`.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I'm following the directions of my Professor and that's what she used. I'm not heavily knowledgeable in Dreamweaver & MySQL.

Comment: Still working on it now, I will let you know when it's all good